# Creating tables and problems with primary key in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, primary-key, mysql2

When I try to run the following code in Rails using Mysql2 as database manager:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I obtain the following error:

```
 rake aborted!
 "Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL:"
```

Why do I get this error, if the primary key in a table by default is NOT "null"?

Migration code, however :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :users do |t|
     t.string "first_name"
     t.timestamps
    end
   end 
end
```

Comment: Please post the code of your migration. Sounds like you maybe have composite PK allowing nulls.

Comment: I didn't added, because I don't see anything weird there. However, I add it to the question

Comment: What's your MySQL version. It looks like a very recent version conflicts with an older Rails version: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247  Can you update Rails?

Comment: I have the latest version of Ruby (2.0.0p53), Rails (4.0.2) and I have MySQL server version 5.7 all for 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot of Mr. Berkowski! I downgraded MySQL server from 5.7 to 5.6 and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 86):

I had a same problem before, and I solved according to here
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247#issuecomment-32425844

> With Rails 2.3.5, MySQL version 5.7.9 and mysql gem you need to have
>   this bit as an initializer in
>   config/initializers/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:
>
> ```
> class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter
>   NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
> end
> ```
>
> For mysql2, it should be config/initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb:
>
> ```
> class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
>   NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
> end
> ```

Answer (score 29):

From the mysql 5.7 breaking change page:

> Columns in a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL, but if declared explicitly
>   as NULL produced no error. Now an error occurs. For example, a
>   statement such as CREATE TABLE t (i INT NULL PRIMARY KEY) is rejected.
>   The same occurs for similar ALTER TABLE statements. (Bug #13995622,
>   Bug #66987, Bug #15967545, Bug #16545198)

[Changes in MySQL 5.7.3 (2013-12-03, Milestone 13)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html)

This issue [was fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247) 3 months ago. I don't know what Rails version it's going to be part of

monkey patch is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247#issuecomment-32425844)

**EDIT:**
It's been more than a year that this fix was merged into master. So, it must be part of the last version of Rails.

**EDIT:**
Indeed, the commit that fixes this can be found at: https://github.com/yahonda/rails/commit/b6655885ef13cf8d1705dc9b5232846f0207febd , and shows that the fix is included in `v4.2.0.beta1, v4.1.6.rc1, v4.1.5, v4.1.4, v4.1.3, v4.1.2, v4.1.2.rc3, v4.1.2.rc2, v4.1.2.rc1, v4.1.1, v4.1.0, v4.1.0.rc2, v4.1.0.rc1, v4.1.0.beta2, v4.1.0.beta1`.  If upgrading to at least v4.1.0 is an option for you, then it should fix the problem.

Comment: FYI, monkey patch required for Rails 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34555109/293280

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue running a rails 4.0.x app using mysql 5.7.x. I was able to fix it by upgrading to rails 4.2.x and upgrading my gems.

(I'm sure these gemfiles need work, but hopefully they are still helpful)

Old Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.13'
gem 'mysql2'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'whenever'

gem 'thin'
gem 'faye'
gem 'faye-websocket'

#pdf generation
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

# Assets
gem 'backbone-on-rails', '~> 0.9.9'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '=1.8.0'
gem 'ejs'                                   # uses templates for backbone
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'neat'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.8.3'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'embedly'                         # Url to Attachment Processing
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'flamegraph'
gem 'fog'                     # s3 storage
gem 'globalize'   # I18n for tagging, etc.
gem 'globalize-accessors'
gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'select2-rails'                   # Token Fields
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'rails_autolink'                  # Convert urls to links
gem 'redis', '3.2.1'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip'        # Zip files together
gem 'unf'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.0.3', require: 'mailgun'

# Deployments
gem 'mina'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "= 2.14.2"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', :require => false
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.9.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: nil
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.0"
  gem 'guard', '>=2.1.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '= 4.2.9'
  gem 'spring', '1.3.6'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'foreman'
end
```

New Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'stackprof'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'whenever'

gem 'thin'
gem 'faye'
gem 'faye-websocket'

#pdf generation
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

# Assets
gem 'backbone-on-rails', '~> 0.9.9'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '=1.8.0'
gem 'ejs'                                   # uses templates for backbone
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'neat'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.8.3'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'embedly'                         # Url to Attachment Processing
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'flamegraph'
gem 'fog'                     # s3 storage
gem 'globalize'   # I18n for tagging, etc.
gem 'globalize-accessors'
gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'select2-rails'                   # Token Fields
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'rails_autolink'                  # Convert urls to links
gem 'redis', '3.2.1'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip'        # Zip files together
gem 'unf'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.0.3', require: 'mailgun'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

# Deployments
gem 'mina'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "= 2.14.2"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', :require => false
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.9.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: nil
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.0"
  gem 'guard', '>=2.1.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '= 4.2.9'
  gem 'spring', '1.6.1'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'foreman'
end
```