# rake db migration issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

So I am following along with Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training at lynda.com.  I've made it to Ch.6 "Generating Migrations".

My problem is when I run `rake db:migrate`, I get:

```
== 20160918162646 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `first_name` varchar(25), `last_name` varchar(50), `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL, `password` varchar(40), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/bryanbean/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20160918162646_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `first_name` varchar(25), `last_name` varchar(50), `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL, `password` varchar(40), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/bryanbean/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20160918162646_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead
/Users/bryanbean/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20160918162646_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why are my databases not migrating?

Migration File:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40

      # t.datetime "created_at"
      # t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users 
  end

end
```

Comment: Post your migration file so we can see what's going on.

Comment: run 'bundle update' and try running 'rake db:migrate' again

Comment: It still gives me the error listed above

Comment: Have a look:  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247#issuecomment-32425844

Comment: thanks dkp! that got it

Comment: @Billyin4c This should works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742967/primary-key-issue-with-creating-tables-in-rails-using-rake-dbmigrate-command-wi