# Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run Peatio, an asset exchange. While migrating DB

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

I am getting following error.

> == 20130624011823 CreateMembers: migrating ====================================
>   -- create_table(:members) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you
>   need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `members` (`id`
>   int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `sn` varchar(255),
>   `name` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `pin_digest` varchar(255),
>   `identity_id` int(11), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime)
>   ENGINE=InnoDB/home/firdoeshalikhan/Desktop/peatio/db/migrate/20130624011823_create_members.rb:3:in
>   `change' ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: All parts of a
>   PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE
>   instead: CREATE TABLE`members`(`id`int(11) DEFAULT NULL
>   auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,`sn`varchar(255),`name`varchar(255),`
>   email`varchar(255),`pin_digest`varchar(255),`identity_id
>   `int(11),`created_at`datetime,`updated_at`datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   /home/firdoeshalikhan/Desktop/peatio/db/migrate/20130624011823_create_members.rb:3:in`
>   change' Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL;
>   if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead
>   /home/firdoeshalikhan/Desktop/peatio/db/migrate/20130624011823_create_members.rb:3:in
>   `change' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to Rails 4.0.12 not being compatible with MySQL 5.7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075515/creating-tables-and-problems-with-primary-key-in-rails

Comment: Either attempt to upgrade by changing the rails version in the Gemfile or use the workaround. Upgrading to 4.1x will fix it but 4.2x is preferable as it includes numerous security fixes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html